# If road lengths are raster layer, how to calculate road lengths for different buffers?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder

A question related calculation of road layer lengths using raster layer for land use regression.

If raster layers are used instead of vector layer for calculation of land use area and road lengths, how can we represent the road lengths layer as a raster layer and how can we calculate road lengths in raster layer for different buffers?

How can we build a model for this using ModelBuilder?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Do you want to know the length of the road network within each cell of your raster layer?

Comment: Damien,
Yes' i want to calculate length of the road network within each cell of raster layer. Secondly using same raster layer i want to calculate total length of road network that fall inside of a circular buffer.

Answer (score 1):

See this homepage, which seem to have similar goals then you:
http://www.personal.psu.edu/users/a/g/agc135/586/Project6/Project6.html

If you work with a raster file, then there is no need to use the Model builder, unless you have many raster files. In that case, I would recommend the ArcGIS help on the model builder as a general introduction.

You could also transform the raster data into a line feature.